# DocuSign Accounts & Credits writing off

Tags: integration, customization, docusignapi, subscription, user-accounts

we are working on a custom software integration with DocuSign.

DocuSign has many types of accounts and subscriptions providing certain limits of features and credits for these features. E.g. you can create 5 documents - so you have 5 credits to create documents.

We have custom software and one corporate DocuSign account within it, enterprise level.
And there are numerous (account1, account2, account3, etc.) accounts of DocuSign users. These users work with our custom software and as a result our corporate account.

We have a question: 
our custom software connects to account1, account2, account3, etc. using our Key. And our custom software creates envelopes(documents) in account1, e.g.

From what account credits are written off?

From our corporate DocuSing account or from DocuSign user account?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The user account should have the appropriate subscription to send envelopes.

Comment: Thank you, still it doesn't explain the question from what account credits are written off